# How to delete the odd columns in an Excel file with VBA (or without)

Tags: excel, vba

Ok, i have this dataset where I need to delete startin from column for every other column. So i tried to do this with VBA since the dataset is quite large. I tried this but it will not work:

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    For clNumber = 4 To 500

    clNumber.Select                      //doesn't work
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Next

End Sub
```

Any ideas on how to select the column of which the number is clNumber and delete that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `clNumber` to `Columns(clNumber)`, as `clNumber` is just a number, but not an object.

Actually, it is better just to use

```
For clNumber = 4 To 500
  Columns(clNumber).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Next
```

as `Select` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
Columns(clNumber).Select
```

Comment: `step 2` is not needed. As 1 columns has already been deleted, only _default_ `step 1` is needed.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
For clNumber = 4 To 500

Columns(clNumber).Select               
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Next
```

Comment: `step 2` is not needed. As 1 columns has already been deleted, only _default_ `step 1` is needed.